# when to use % or em or ex with css font?

Tags: css

can somebody tell me when to use %, em, ex as fonts unit of measurement when dealing with css ? am confuse

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's really up to you. For usability's sake, stick with em or % as px is a fixed value and won't scale (or shouldn't that is) on different devices. Set your base font-size first on the body (67% is a popular one) and then use em's to modify that size to your liking.

---

To pluck [the answer from the web](https://kyleschaeffer.com/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs-percent):

> 1. “Ems” (em): The “em” is a scalable unit that is used in web document media. An em is equal to the current font-size, for instance,
>    if the font-size of the document is 12pt, 1em is equal to 12pt. Ems
>    are scalable in nature, so 2em would equal 24pt, .5em would equal 6pt,
>    etc. Ems are becoming increasingly popular in web documents due to
>    scalability and their mobile-device-friendly nature.
> 2. Pixels (px): Pixels are fixed-size units that are used in screen media (i.e. to be read on the computer screen). One pixel is equal to
>    one dot on the computer screen (the smallest division of your screen’s
>    resolution). Many web designers use pixel units in web documents in
>    order to produce a pixel-perfect representation of their site as it is
>    rendered in the browser. One problem with the pixel unit is that it
>    does not scale upward for visually-impaired readers or downward to fit
>    mobile devices.
> 3. Points (pt): Points are traditionally used in print media (anything that is to be printed on paper, etc.). One point is equal to
>    1/72 of an inch. Points are much like pixels, in that they are
>    fixed-size units and cannot scale in size.
> 4. Percent (%): The percent unit is much like the “em” unit, save for a few fundamental differences. First and foremost, the current
>    font-size is equal to 100% (i.e. 12pt = 100%). While using the percent
>    unit, your text remains fully scalable for mobile devices and for
>    accessibility.

I'd highly recommend reading this article, it explains the whole thing in detail with diagrams :)